# Unable to install foreman in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, foreman, puppet-foreman

I am trying to install foreman in ubuntu 12.04, After adding apt source and executing foreman-installer command giving me the below error.

**/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/kafo/puppet_module_parser.rb:21:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Puppet::Parser::Parser (NameError)**

Couldn't find much in google....

How to solve it??

Comment: Why Ubuntu 12.04? Use 14.04 or 16.04. The version of ruby is likey too old.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux] Brightbox. Thats the version, foremain won't support this version of ruby ??

Comment: This is server and I have a bunch of production web servers running in it, I dont want to upgrade to 14.04 and stop other application working